# What is exactly the feature vector output of encode function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-recognition

Matlab documentation for function encode says

> encode returns a feature vector that represents a histogram of visual
>   word occurrences contained in the input image, I.

what exactly does visual word occurrences mean? A value of 0.15 for example, what does it represent? This value is obviously normalized by something but the documentation does not specify exactly what.

Answer (score 0):

visual word occurrences is number of times a word appears in an image. histogram is always items vs counts so it should return array *word verses word_occurances*

Comment: The documentation says that the values are L2 normalized. How does this work exactly? If I choose 'Normalization', 'none' only then is the vector comprised of integers.

Comment: L2 normalization is popularly known as least squares, I guess counts are divided by lease square error or some similar operation for normalization.